# jQuery charset iso-8859-1 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, character-encoding

it's days that i'm trying to figure out how charset works.
I'm sending via form using ajax a string like: §test the output cannot recognize the "§" case.
This is my code:

```
    var messaggio = $("input[name='messaggio']").val();
    $.ajax({
    url:"js/php/sendchat.php",
    data:"messaggio="+messaggio,
    type:"post",
    contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1",
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
    jqXHR.overrideMimeType('application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1');
},
    success:function(data){
            $("input[name='messaggio']").val("");
        $("body").html(data);
    }
});
```

This on: sendchat.php

```
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

And this on index where's my application:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chat.js" charset="ISO-8859-1"></script>
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How exactly does the output fail to recognise `§`? Do you actually save your files and data as ISO-8859-1? (Saying that a text is ISO-8859-1 doesn't make it ISO-8859-1 automatically.)

Comment: The output is: Â§Test...
I'm using dreawaver cs6, so, i don't know how it saves files...

Comment: @Priya Do this: 1) Remove all encoding hints everywhere. JavaScript, Meta tags, Content-Type header. 2) Then load the page in the browser. Check what the browser auto-detected as the page encoding. (If the page does not look right, switch encodings manually until it's ok.) 3) Declare that page encoding via the Content-Type header *only*. Nowhere else.

Comment: Thank you @Tomalak it's working, i've another problem about it and i open another post :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
          jqXHR.overrideMimeType("text/html;charset=iso-8859-1");
        }
```

Comment: Did it, but still this the output: Â§Test and what i wrote is §Test